# S3cmd sync returns "killed"

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am trying to sync a few large buckets on amazon S3.

When I run my S3cmd sync --recursive command I get a response saying "killed".

What does this refer to? Is there a limit on the number of files that can be synced in S3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After reading around it looks like the program has memory consumption issues. In particular this can cause the [OOM killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) (out of memory killer) to take down the process and prevent the system from getting bogged down. A quick look at `dmesg` after the process is killed will generally show if this is the case or not.

With that in mind I would ensure you're on the latest release, which notes memory consumption issues being solved in the [release notes](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-150a1-released).

Comment: Right on the button. However, after installing s3cmd from the latest source the process is still getting killed. I might have to bump up the memory on my EC2 instance or take one of these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15266865/242426

Comment: I was running into this as well, but I was running in a Vagrant. With the tip that it was a memory issue, I checked my vagrant settings and found that I was running the vm with only 256mb. Once I bumped that up the problem was fixed.

Comment: Same here, increasing of memory (in my case from 512MB to 2GB) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I would like to say that, before you try to add more physical memory or increase vm memory, try just adding more swap.

I did this with 4 servers (ubuntu and centos) with low ram (700MB total, only 15MB available) and it is working fine now.